# Android App run for computation only

Tags: android, build

My question is simple. How can i perform a run of my apk file for computation only on Android Studio.

I only need the Log.d calls in order to troubleshoot 
any computation problems. Don't want the graphics.

Thanks for help

Comment: Which graphics?

Comment: You can create a service. However, wouldn't it be easier to have a simple UI?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a service. But to view the logcat, you must plug your device into a desktop or laptop. Why go to all the trouble when you can just program the computer directly?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should look for unit test , just for testing your code logic without UI.

Answer (score -1):

How can you debug without UI??? I think this is impossible.

Comment: Services do not have a UI.

Comment: Thought there was a way just to run the code without actually executing the App. I think there must be a way.